# Injecting / passing objects from python file to jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to pass an object / python module to jupyter notebook. Which I 
then want to use from notebook and access the functions of that object. Is it even possible?

I know that we can pass normal parameters, integers, strings etc. Also I am aware that there are libraries like papermill to achieve this task. However, I am unable to find a way to inject objects.

Here is what I want to achieve.

```
def function(object):
     #this recieves the object which needs to be injected to jupyter notebook
     inject_to_notebook(object)

def inject_to_notebook(inject_obj):
    # THis should create a new notebook file from where I can access all the functions defined in the inject_obj
    # Or access the members in inject_obj
```

*Notes:

- The object is coming from a c compiled code/app

Comment: why don't you just `import` the external python module into your notebook?

Comment: I can import this external module to the notebook, yes you are right. However, the probem is that, I can only call a python function from the software executable. Which cann pass an object to only a python script function(with some c specific objects in it). This exe can not directly call jupyter notebook. So that's why I was wondering if there is a workaround to forward this object to the notebook

Comment: `int` and `str` are all "normal objects", so if you can do it with those...

Comment: I thought the same. So when I use the int and strings as parameter from papermill library it works fine. When I then try to pass a object I get this error
   """
      can't pickle module objects
   """

Comment: I don't know anything about that library, but it seems to rely on `pickle`, which will not work with module objects, but why are you trying to pass a module object in the first place? You are going to need to provide more information about what exactly you are doing and what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry about less info. The object I want to forward is actually coming from a c application. The executable can call a python function and passes a object to the function. Which provides all the functionalities from the c app.

Comment: nice idea. what kind of object? a class , a string , a int?

Comment: The object actually holds the functions from a c++ class. All the functionalities are defined in C++ app.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ext/callingPython.html